# Open prettyPhoto popup with aspx page inside on GridView button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, prettyphoto

At the moment I have an aspx page with a gridview on it. I would like to add a prettyPhoto popup which appears on a button click within the gridview. The popup will have details of the selected row. My gridview looks like this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvBacklog" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="BacklogID" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive" DataSourceID="ldsBacklog" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BacklogID" HeaderText="Backlog ID" SortExpression="BacklogID" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Story" SortExpression="Story.StoryName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("Story.StoryName") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <itemtemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Id="txtStoryName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Story.StoryName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </itemtemplate>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Story.StoryDesc">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval ("Story.StoryDesc") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <itemtemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Id="txtDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Story.StoryDesc")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </itemtemplate>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Story Points" SortExpression="Story.StoryPoints">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval ("Story.StoryPoints") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFibbonacci" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Story.StoryPoints")%>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Story.Size">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval ("Story.Size") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WSJF Score" SortExpression="Story.WSJFScore">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval ("Story.WSJFScore") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sprint" SortExpression="Sprint.SprintNumber">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("Sprint.SprintNumber") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSprint" DataSourceID="ldsSprint" DataValueField="SprintNumber" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Sprint.SprintNumber") %>' runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Added By" SortExpression="User.Username">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval ("User.Username") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" CommandName="Delete">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Any tips or advice would be really helpful! I've looked online and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: what exactly have you lookup or googled on line .. are you familiar with JavaScript there are many ways to skin this cat.. but depending on what you are familiar with would determine what someone would or could recommend.. `JavaScript, JQuery, AngularJS, Ajax, 3rd Party tools like Telerik`...etc...

Answer (score 0):

Performing a popup from a gridview is a tricky business. The act of Selecting a row causes a postback which plays havoc with trying to manage the Client side popup code.  You have to do some hoop jumping to make the popup appear after the postback completes. But causing a postback kind of defeats the purpose of using a popup to begin with.

So one way to handle this is to make sure all the detail information is available on the initial pass.  You can do this by embedding a DetailsView (with it's own datasource that is populated with the key from the current row) in a hidden div embedded in an new or existing template field in the current GridView.

Or, if you are ok with the postback, just throw a hidden div containing the DetailsView on the current page below everything else and just work out the logic to display the now populated DV after post completes.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Bootstrap modal to implement the functionality.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
})
```